# Android: UTF-8 encoded HTTP response to String

Tags: android, http, utf-8, connection

I am trying to convert a UTF-8 data to String. The UTF-8 data is obtained by HTTP connection.
My problem is the converted String does not display UTF-8 Characters properly.

Here is my code {extra bits removed }

```
URLConnection urlconn = url.openConnection();
httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlconn;
httpConn.connect();
InputStream in= httpConn.getInputStream();
String text = "";
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8");
int charRead;
char[] inputBuffer = new char[2048];


while((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0){
String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
text += readString;
inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER];
}
```

Where am i doing wrong ? The generated text is not UTF-8 !!

Thanks

Comment: Side note: If you have a block of code, highlight the entire code and press CTRL+K. Makes it look much better.

Comment: thanks for formatting tip . updated the question

Comment: You are reading into inputBuffer which is of type char. I don't think it is suitable for UTF-8. Only ASCII chars

Comment: so should i be reading in a byte[] buffer ?